# GoogleMaps-API: don't drive through certain streets or regions

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, here-api

Is there a feature in the GoogleMaps-API that allows me to force a route not to use a certain street or region? (Similar to [excludeZones](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-calculate-route.html) in the Here-API?

My use case is routing for bigger trucks in cities that have to avoid smaller streets or residential areas.

Comment: Would some of the voters care to explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature in Google Maps APIs. Even more, there is a very old feature request in the Google issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35816642

As you can see this feature was requested in 2008 (10 years ago!), but unfortunately it is not implemented yet.

You can star the feature request to join other 188 people who voted for it and subscribe to further notifications.

Comment: Thanks! I had a closer look at the here-api and will use it instead of google maps.